# Parsing time if valid

Tags: javascript, datetime, regex

I need to parse only valid timestamp formats:

- Hours followed by minutes followed by seconds: `t=1h2m3s`
- Minutes followed by seconds: `t=2m3s`
- Only hours: `t=3h`
- Only minutes: `t=4m`
- Only seconds: `t=5s` and escape other timestamp formats like `t=2m1h` or `t=3s2m` or `t=3s1h2m`.

To get the hours, minutes and seconds, I use this Regex. Let me know any improvement can be done to make it simple.

```
function calculateInSeconds(timeStamp) {
  var timeInSeconds=0;
  if(timeStamp.match(/t=[0-9]*h?[0-9]*m?[0-9]*s?/g).toString()==timeStamp){
    timeStamp.replace(/([0-9]+)[h|m|s]/g, function(match, value) {
       if (match.indexOf("h") > -1) {
          timeInSeconds += value * 60 * 60;
       } else if (match.indexOf("m") > -1) {
                timeInSeconds += value * 60;
       } else if (match.indexOf("s") > -1) {
                timeInSeconds += value * 1;
       }
     });
   }
   console.log("timeInSeconds"+timeInSeconds);
}

calculateInSeconds("t=3m59s1h");//invalid
calculateInSeconds("t=1m59s");//valid
calculateInSeconds("t=1h");//valid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you may improve your regexps a bit using classes: replace `[0-9]` by `\d`.

In the other hand, you may strongly improve performance by:

- defining an object with the unit values: `units: {h: 3600, m: 60, s: 1};`
- modifying the 2nd regexp to directly provide the current unit:
  `timeStamp.replace(/(\d+)(\w)/g, function(match, value, unit) {`
  (note that `\w` is enough since your previous test eliminated any wrong value)
- then using a unique computation in the function: `timeInSeconds += value * units[unit];`

So the entire snippet becomes:

```
function calculateInSeconds(timeStamp) {
  var timeInSeconds = 0,
    units = {
    h: 3600,
    m: 60,
    s: 1,
  };
  if (timeStamp.match(/t=\d*h?\d*m?\d*s?/g).toString() == timeStamp){
    timeStamp.replace(/(\d+)(\w)/g, function(match, value, unit) {
      timeInSeconds += value * units[unit];
    });
  }
  console.log(timeStamp + ' -> ' + timeInSeconds + ' seconds');
}

calculateInSeconds("t=3m59s1h"); //invalid
calculateInSeconds("t=1m59s"); //valid
calculateInSeconds("t=1h"); //valid
```

BTW I like the idea of your first test to isolate valid timeStamps.

Comment: This was my first thought; I went down a different path to eliminate two separate Regex parses on the same string, but I think your conciseness wins.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches things that make no sense, like `t=9999` or `t=00m9`

Try this:

`/t=(?=.)(?:\d+h)?(?:\d+m)?(?:\d+s)?$/`

https://regex101.com/r/vM8gE8/2

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex accepts the formats `t=1h2s` and `t=1h2m`. I'm not sure if this is intentional or not.

Your Regex also accepts `t=1hms`, `t=h1ms`, and `t=hm1s`. Technically, `t=hms` passes your matching Regex as well, though it will output 0 like an invalid match. These cases can be eliminated by changing your 0-or-more `*` symbols to 1-or-more `+` symbols. Since this is Code Review, I'll retain your original functionality in my answer.

Finally, you're using pipes within your character set `[h|m|s]` when you shouldn't be: as characters within a character set are treated as literals, this includes `|` as a valid matching character (i.e., `\d*[h|m|s]` would successfully match `65|`). It should just be `[hms]`.

---

`timeStamp.match(...)==timeStamp` seems to be used to make sure the expression matches the whole string, but there are better ways to accomplish this. In Regex, you can specify `^` and `$` as the start and end of the string respectively.

You can combine the match and replace into a single expression, since the replace won't do anything if it fails to match. Then you can use Regex groups to capture the hours, minutes, and seconds.

Finally, you can replace `[0-9]` in your regular expression to the digit (`\d`) character set, which represents the same thing. This is only really useful if you're interested in shortening the pattern; I don't think it improves readability.

Putting everything together, we get the following Regex pattern:

```
/^t=(?:(\d*)h)?(?:(\d*)m)?(?:(\d*)s)?$/
```

Breaking it down:

```
/^t=                                      ## The start of the string
    (?:                                   ## Non-capturing group
       (\d*)h                             ## Capturing hours in a group
             )?                           ## Specifying the group as optional
               (?:(\d*)m)?                ## Same for minutes
                          (?:(\d*)s)?     ## Same for seconds
                                     $/   ## The end of the string
```

Resulting in the following JavaScript code:

```
function calculateInSeconds(timeStamp) {
  var timeInSeconds = 0;
  timeStamp.replace(/^t=(?:(\d*)h)?(?:(\d*)m)?(?:(\d*)s)?$/, function(match, hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var hoursInSeconds, minutesInSeconds;

    hoursInSeconds = hours * 60 * 60 || 0;
    minutesInSeconds = minutes * 60 || 0;
    seconds = seconds * 1 || 0;

    timeInSeconds = hoursInSeconds + minutesInSeconds + seconds;
  });
  console.log("timeInSeconds"+timeInSeconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first regex allows things like `"t=hms"` with no digits at all, or `"t=123"` with no letters. The next regex, however, expects at least 1 of either.

Your regex isn't anchored either, so it'll match stuff anywhere in the string. I assume the string is supposed to be *just* the `t=...` timecode in order to be valid.

There's also the question of whether you should allow second/minute values greater than 59. Your current code allows `"t=61s"` just fine, though it'd be more natural to say "1m1s". But saying "61s" shouldn't cause trouble in the calculation, so let's keep it.

Structure-wise, I'd get by with one match call. But more importantly, I'd make the function return the number of seconds - not log it. The function's purpose is to parse the timecode, nothing else. If you want to log it, you can do that elsewhere; it's not the function's purpose.

```
function timecodeInSeconds(timecode) {
  var seconds = 0;

  if(match = timecode.match(/^t=(?:(\d+)h)?(?:(\d+)m)?(?:(\d+)s)?$/)) {
    seconds += match[1] ? match[1] * 3600 : 0
    seconds += match[2] ? match[2] * 60 : 0
    seconds += match[3] ? match[3] * 1 : 0
    return seconds;
  }

  return null;
}
```

The only issue with the above is that it accepts `"t="`. That can be handled if a simple `if`, though:

```
if(!match[1] && !match[2] && !match[3]) return null;
```

Comment: You can simplify those ternaries to a null coalescing operator (e.g., `seconds += match[1] * 3600 || 0;`).